# Is it a good practice to pass an object of Android Activity to a Thread class' constructor?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

While writing an Android activity that submits input queries to a web server, I was thinking instead of having an anonymous inner class to define the networking thread, why can't we use a separate class that extends Thread.

While this works as expected, I would like to know whether this belongs any good or bad practice.

```
public class GreetActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_greet_activity);
    }

    public void onClickBtn(View v){
         Thread t = new WorkerThread("http://10.0.2.2:8080",this);
         t.start();
    }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread{
    private String targetURL;
    private Activity activity;

    public WorkerThread(String url, Activity act){
         this.activity = act;
         this.targetURL = url;
    }

    public void run(){
         TextView tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
         . . . . . . 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Passing an `Activity` reference to a thread has some caveats. Activity lifecycle is separate from thread lifecycle. Activities can be destroyed and recreated e.g. by orientation change events. If the activity reference is hold in a thread, the resources held by the activity (lots of bitmap assets for example, taking a lot of memory) are not garbage collectible.

   An non-static inner class also has the same problem since the reference to the parent is implicit.

   A working solution is to clear the activity reference when the activity is destroyed, and supply a new activity reference when the activity is recreated.
2. You can only touch your UI widgets in the UI thread as mentioned by blackbelt.

For what it's worth, an `AsyncTask` is easier to work with than a bare-bones `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, no it is not, since only the `UI Thread` can touch  the UI, your code will make your application crashes with

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, When I executed the code, it got executed successfully. I will try to understand more on the cause and update the thread.

Comment: it is find to look for a View. Changing its content is wrong. @lallto answer is really good